# Client Server Communication Android

Tags: android, client, server, message

How can we sent request to server with specific format in android for example

[RequestID-1byte][sourceID-1byte][datalen-4byte][Data Part]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think you can do something like that with `Volley Library`:

```
StringRequest mStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_VALIDATE, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            // code for response here
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // code for error response here
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, Byte> getParams() {
            Map<String, Byte> params = new HashMap<>();
            // the POST parameters:
            params.put("RequestID", byte1);
            params.put("sourceID", byte2);
            params.put("datalen", byte3);
            return params;
        }
    };

    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(mStringRequest);
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

use server-client socket programming?

i writing sample code.

```
public class Packet {

    private byte requestID;
    private byte sourceID;
    private byte[] data;

    public Packet(byte requestID, byte sourceID, byte[] data) {
        this.requestID = requestID;
        this.sourceID = sourceID;
        // TODO: add exception handling for data length > 65535, data length more 4byte
        this.data = data;
    }

    public byte[] getData() throws IOException{

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byteStream.write(requestID);
        byteStream.write(sourceID);

        if(data.length<0xff) // if data length < 255, data byte is 2
            byteStream.write(0);
        byteStream.write((short)data.length);
        byteStream.write(data);
        byteStream.close();
        return byteStream.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

and socket I/O

```
Socket socket = new Socket(somehost, someport);

InputStream inStream = socket.getInputStream();
OutputStream outStream = socket.getOutputStream();
...
...
byte requestID = 1;
byte sourceID = 2;
byte data[] = ....

Packet packet = new Packet(requestID,sourceID,data);
outStream.write(packet.getData());
outStream.flush();
...
...
```